# sdkmanager does not list all packages? (using cmdline-tools)

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I was just trying to configure my machine to be able to test some android apps.
Some of the things I will need will be `adb` and `uiautomatorviewer`. To get `adb`, was easy, just had to download `platform-tools` from android website. However, when it came to get `uiautomatorviewer` everything went from easy to difficult pretty fast.

I looked into here https://www.guru99.com/uiautomatorviewer-tutorial.html and as you can see they mention that they install the whole Android studio just to retrieve `uiautomatorviewer` (which I definitely don't need).

I then noticed that when trying to download android we can download the command line tools only, which is great! Inside, it contained the sdkmanager so I should be able to download everything I needed. So now, following some help from android official website I was able to list all the packages available (the same list that is visible through the Android Studio UI, when opening the SDK Manager). I downloaded multiple packages, just to see which one would bring `uiautomatorviewer` - none of the listed one's did (I even tried changing channels and list packages). Also, I tried to look into android documentation but couldn't find anything saying which package has `uiautomatorviewer`, even on Android official docs.

Back to searching.. On a new blog, someone mentioned something about a `tools` folder https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/uiautomator-tutorial/#2_Command-line_Tools_Only

So I just tried to do the command `sdkmanager "tools"` and voilá, inside that package, there it was `uiautomatorviewer`.

So my question is: why is this not showing somewhere? Did I overlook something? I feel that for such a easy setup I had to go into hell and come back (I've also seen that these folders got changed through the years, but even so.. ). Also was there a easier setup (without installing Android Studio)

Thanks!